# Is there an idiomatic expression for "treating a story freely"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an idiomatic expression which means "treating an original story freely". For example, a film director takes an old traditional story and treats it freely in his/her adaptation by making a lot of changes to the original story. I'm not even sure if it is correct English to say, "X treated the story freely", because I couldn't find anything like that on Google Books, Google News, etc.

Comment: I could write an answer and suggest that *the director has taken liberties with the original story* but then, I fear, we'd get into a discussion about whether that was any better than your original.  What are the characteristics of the expression you seek, especially those which distinguish it from the expression you already have?

Comment: Your own word, *adaptation,* is a good one, especially if there are "a lot of changes to the original story," as in a screen adaptation of a book.

Comment: No, it's not quite idiomatic ('treated freely' usually referring to healthcare systems!) . 'Bernstein and Sondheim's  _freely adapted_  version of "Romeo and Juliet" ' sounds more natural.

Comment: The movie is ***loosely based on** [some traditional story or historical record]*. There are many ways of saying something like this, so it's a POB question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm already familiar with "loose adaptation". As my example illustrates, I'm looking for an expression with "director" as the subject.

Comment: *The director **loosely based** his movie on Homer's Iliad*. You're seriously restricting yourself if you insist on an "active verb" usage, rather than a passive usage, or a noun-based element.